# Import csv into HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, bigdata

Hi am trying to import an csv file into HBase database and while doing that I am getting following exception

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:635)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1257)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1245)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.func_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:5069)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.store_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:7667)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1580)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1013)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:553)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1648)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1621)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:575)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1093)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.WritableByteArrayComparable
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 27 more
================================================================================
```

And I figured it out that we need to specify the classpath of the hbase to pig.
We are using clustered environment, and I dont have any idea where should I specify the classpath statements as like the following

```
export HBASE_HOME=/opt/mapr/hbase/hbase-0.98.7
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=.`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath`:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.